# PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart() returns null

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to get the active part in my eclipse plugin, using this code, but instead I get `null`:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart();
```

I found that I should put the above code in a thread, so I have changed my code to be:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart();
    }
});
```

But I still get `null`!

(When I use asyncExec it finds the active part, but the asyncExec does not match my need because I need the active part immediately.)

Comment: Where are you trying to access the active part? Are you getting NULL or a NullPointerException? Is it possible that the application has not started completely yet? What Eclipse version are u using?

Comment: Where are you calling this code? The active part will be null during startup for example.